# What’s the meaning of “could” and “would” in this text explaining grammar rule?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, modal-verbs

After looking up “would” and “could”, I couldn’t find any relevant meaning in the use of **would** and **could** in this text, which I found on a [British Council page](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/clause-phrase-and-sentence/verb-patterns/reporting-reports-and-summaries):

> You **could** go on in the same way. You **would** use past tense forms to talk about something which happened ten years ago. So tense forms in reports and summaries in English are the same as in the rest of the language.

What if I use **can** and **will**? Is it ok?

Comment: What exactly is the problem, in your view?

Comment: I have voted to close this question because it does not give the url of the text in question. Without such a citation, it is impossible to see the text in context and therefore impossible to give any explanation of any actual question about English grammar. I shall change my vote if the question is edited to provide the link.

Comment: @JeffMorrow: [Literally the first result for a Bing search for the last sentence in the quote](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/clause-phrase-and-sentence/verb-patterns/reporting-reports-and-summaries).

Comment: @NathanTuggy That still does not justify the OP from giving the relevant  link. But thank you for the link. I have retracted my close vote.

Comment: I meant "not giving" in my previous comment.

Comment: Ok. I’m sorry that I didn’t provide the link because I thought it is not a problem. Now I will make my question more specific after seeing the answers.

Comment: I don't see the passage in the page linked to.

Answer (score 1):

The context is that a sentence was introduced with "it might be written as" with the clear implication that the thought could be expressed in other ways. So the "could" just recognizes that the example just given does not prevent use of a different form of expression going forward. The "would" is meant to specify how to proceed if the preceding example is used as a model going forward.

Comment: @user67265 Adding to this, the reason why the text uses "could" and not "can" (and "would" and not "will") is that it's describing a **hypothetical situation** with the **subjunctive** mood.  'Could' is the subjunctive of 'can' and 'would' is the subjunctive of 'will.' The indicative mood forms 'can' and 'will' would be much less common in this context.  "You *can* go on in the same way..." sounds very informal to me (not something that would be in a grammar textbook!) and "You 'will' use past tense forms..." sounds plain wrong (I think that's because it could be confused with the imperative).

Answer (score 0):

In this context, "could" and "would" are synonymous.

Comment: No, they're not.

Answer (score 0):

I think "could" and  "would" would be the softer tone than "can" and "will"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).